# How to make local changes reflect in docker container upon saving

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to play with docker and I am still in the process of setting up my development environment. I am trying to set up my container in such a way that I can save changes on the host machine and have them propagated to the container.

I thought by using a `volume` I was mounting my local ./code directory into the container. I was hoping that by doing this I could run `docker-compose up`, develop, save and have those changes pushed into the container. Though after saving I am not seeing my changes reflected in the app until I kill it and run `docker-compose up` again. Am I using the correct concepts? or is this possible with docker?

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10.13-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV production
# RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  express-docker-test:
    build: code
    # command: npm install --production --silent && mv node_modules ../
    volumes:
      - E:\git\express-docker-test\code\:/code/
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
    expose:
      - "3000"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    command: npm start
```

Here is a test [repo I am experimenting with](https://github.com/jburns24/express-docker-test). I would like it if I could, with this repo, run `docker-compose up`. Then make an edit to the response say go from

```
- Hello world!!!
+ Hello World.
```

and then be able to refresh localhost:3000 and see the new response.

#### Results from `docker inspect express-docker-test_express-docker-test`

```
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:791e8fbd5c871af53a37f5e9f5058e423f8ddf914b09f21ff1d80a40ea4f142f",
        "RepoTags": [
            "express-docker-test_express-docker-test:latest"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [],
        "Parent": "sha256:e87553281ff90e49977fb6166c70c0e5ebf7bb98f0ae06468d7883dc0314c606",
        "Comment": "",
        "Created": "2019-07-14T19:15:47.1174538Z",
        "Container": "8426c3db78c23c1cfc594c500ce77adf81ddd43ca52ca58456ba5b49ec60fee9",
        "ContainerConfig": {
            "Hostname": "8426c3db78c2",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "NODE_VERSION=10.13.0",
                "YARN_VERSION=1.10.1",
                "NODE_ENV=production"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "#(nop) WORKDIR /code"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "sha256:e87553281ff90e49977fb6166c70c0e5ebf7bb98f0ae06468d7883dc0314c606",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/code",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": [],
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "DockerVersion": "18.09.2",
        "Author": "",
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "NODE_VERSION=10.13.0",
                "YARN_VERSION=1.10.1",
                "NODE_ENV=production"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "node"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "sha256:e87553281ff90e49977fb6166c70c0e5ebf7bb98f0ae06468d7883dc0314c606",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/code",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": [],
            "Labels": null
        },
        "Architecture": "amd64",
        "Os": "linux",
        "Size": 70255071,
        "VirtualSize": 70255071,
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8a0293f507ec80f68197b3bcb49b12e1a61c08f122a8a85060ab2d766d881a93/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a159e965ecf6e91533397def52fb1b3aef900c9793f933dc5120eed2381a37f4/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/49f6493daf037bc88f9fb474ae71e36f13b58224082ff1f28ee367c795207c8d/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9c4a3691e175f15585034acf7146ce5601f9e9d9c9cb60023bd348172116ae5c/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9c4a3691e175f15585034acf7146ce5601f9e9d9c9cb60023bd348172116ae5c/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9c4a3691e175f15585034acf7146ce5601f9e9d9c9cb60023bd348172116ae5c/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "RootFS": {
            "Type": "layers",
            "Layers": [
                "sha256:df64d3292fd6194b7865d7326af5255db6d81e9df29f48adde61a918fbd8c332",
                "sha256:387bc77dd3f21547b74752dd03f6018b5d750684c832c39cd239704052ce366e",
                "sha256:2faeaaebb1134fe62e2cc1603a761301e281c04a8e2e36ff2ac1005f7c06780f",
                "sha256:dfb2bf93a77a1907921d8f1622e831fa31c924c6c612e593b8937f95e42a0afa"
            ]
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "LastTagTime": "2019-07-14T19:31:00.4646905Z"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: It should be possible and what you are looking for is [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/). Your volume looks like a bind mount already. Can you show the output of  `docker inspect` command on your container that is created by compose? Look for `Mounts` section in the output.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I edited question so that there is a public example of what I am experiencing and included the output you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Don't `RUN mkdir /code` in the Dockerfile.

If you're mounting a local directory into `/code`, then your Dockerfile should just expect it be exist (have been mounted by `docker run ...`--volume=` or by Docker Compose as you have.

Leave `WORKDIR /code`.

I thought mounts had to be absolute paths *but* if `./code` then works, you're good.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have tried your change but did not see the results I thought I would. Posted a test repo that has the same behavior I am experiencing in my other project if you are so inclined to take a closer look.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Conventionally (!) you would not use containers like this. One approach with containers is to make them immutable. By building the container with code that changes, this tenet is broken. Data yes, code no. I understand you're exploring. Eating lunch. Will try it then.

Comment: OK. So the first issue is that, when you build a container image, you don't get to mount volumes. I think a better approach would be to have an app that you `COPY . .` into the container for the build *and* when you run, you can mount a volume and use that. This would entail have more of an immutable build too (which is also preferable).

Comment: Thanks for the info,  I was kinda wondering if that was more of less of them. But that makes me wonder is the idea generally develop and test locally as you normally would (without containers) then use containers for integration testing and production?

Comment: You'd want to build even locally too. This gives you strong confidence that, what you're building and running locally, is what you ship for testing and what goes into production. In truth, when I wanted to test your code, I ran it outside of a container first.... that yield the second issue which is that you need to `RUN npm install` before your container could e.g. `ENTRYPOINT ["npm","start"]`.

Comment: For completeness, another useful debugging step is to 'step' through your Dockerfile. The `node:10.13-alpine` image has an `ENTRYPOINT` of `'npm` (I suspect) but you can force it to run a shell instead `docker run --interactive --tty --volume=.../code:/code node:10.13-alpine ash`

Comment: I see, yeah I ran that locally and forgot to put it in docker file.I think I am starting to understand the purpose of containers more and while I am still interested in my original query. It now seems like a setup like that is not going to result in a system configuration that mirrors a typical docker setup in any real containerized project. Thanks for the information.

Comment: Reproducible deployments.You build it and ship it knowing the recipient can run it too. You're welcome!